# How to verify property type in Javascript class?

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to get an idea how to build `javascript class` that would represent an object like `Person`.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, hobbies) {
        this.name = name; // string
        this.age = age; // number
        this.hobbies = hobbies; // array
    }
}
```

This object will be used in `react/redux-form` to map incoming and outgoing data from/to `database`. My question is how can I enforce `hobbies` are really `array` type or `age` as `number` and `name` as `string` in its class definition? In `java`, I am allowed to build simple data model via strong type of its property `(e.g. String name = null)` and having `getter/setter` method for it.

Comment: does it have to be in JS? or can you use TypeScript instead? (and then transpile it)

Comment: unfortunately I am locked to use only JS.

Comment: you don't need any library or TypeScript or whatever to fulfil your requirement. JavaScript actually provides features to accomplish them and more. I'll demonstrate it in a new answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're not using typescript or some sort of typing library then you have to manage it yourself.  So in your example:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, hobbies) {
        name = typeof name === 'string'?name:null;
        age = typeof age === 'number'?age:null;
        hobbies = Array.isArray(hobbies)?hobbies:null;

        ...
    }
}
```

You might want to do some more in depth checking but this will get you going.

Comment: OP needs to understand how to implement getter/setter in JavaScript. So, this is not sufficient since `hobbies` property can be reassigned a non-array value after construction.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a dynamically typed language which means , the errors occur only once the program is executed. That is, at runtime. This means that a program written in a dynamically-typed language can compile even if it contains type errors that would otherwise prevent the script from running properly.

You'll need to use Typescript for that in react,and it's possible to write react apps in Typescript.  Typescript  a strict syntactical superset of JavaScript, and adds optional static typing to the language. TypeScript is designed for development of large applications and transcompiles to JavaScript

Other than typing getters/setters are supported in JS

Comment: What you are _suggesting_ by this answer is **not** true. Dynamic typing does not imply absence of type checking. Rather while types cannot be checked by static analysis in that case, dynamic type checking remains possible and is a viable option.

Moreover, **large applications can be written in JavaScript where the developers are actually competent in the language**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) along with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to do validation.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, hobbies) {
      let hobbyList = ["sports", "cooking", "movies"];
      
      if(typeof name !== "string"){
        throw "Name must be a string!";
      } else {
        this.name = name;
      }
      
      if(typeof age !== "number"){
        throw "Age must be a number!"
      } else {
        this.age = age; 
      }
      
      if(hobbyList.indexOf(hobbies) <=0){
        throw "Must be a choice from the list"
      } else {
        this.name = name;
      }      
    }
}

let p1 = new Person(12,"twelve", "archery"); // all args are bad - 3 errors
let p2 = new Person("Scott", 52, "movies")   // good - no errors
```

Comment: even better! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from validation on instantiation of the object. Further validation can be done via a setter (as you required) when the property value changes:

```
class Person {

  constructor(name, age, hobbies) {

    if (!Array.isArray(hobbies)) {
      console.error(`Type of hobbies should 'array', found ${typeof hobbies}`);
    }

    Object.defineProperties(this, {

      age: {
        get: () => age,
        set: value => {
          age = value;
        }
      },
      name: {
        get: () => name,
        set: value => {
          name = value;
        }
      },
      hobbies: {
        get: () => hobbies,
        set: value => {
          if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
            console.error(`Type of hobbies should 'array', found ${typeof value}`);
          }
          hobbies = value;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Hence, the following will throw an error

```
const person = new Person ( "Me", 465, "not a list of hobbies" );
```

It's that simple. Learn more at [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

Comment: I greatly appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Person {

    constructor(name, age, hobbies) {
        this.name = name; // string
        this.age = age; // number
        this.hobbies = hobbies; // array
    }
    
    setName(name){
      console.log(typeof name=="string") 
      if(typeof name=="string")
        this.name = name;
        
    }
    
    setAge(age){
     
      if(typeof age=="number")
        this.age = age;
        
    }
    
    
}

let person = new Person('Rahi','45',["dfdsf","dd"])
console.log("....name=%s, age=%s",person.name,person.age);
person.setName("John");
console.log("....name=%s",person.name);
person.setName(9999);
console.log("....name=%s",person.name);

console.log("................");

person.setAge("45");
console.log("....name=%s",person.name);
person.setAge(45);
console.log("....name=%s",person.name);

console.log("....name=%s, age=%s",person.name,person.age);
```

You can check type of on set method to set correct value type.